# Populate Column B with abbreviations for string in Column A

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with two sheets, on Sheet2:ColumnA is a list of words, one per row and Sheet2:ColumnB is their abbreviations. Sheet1:ColumnA is a string of words space delimited.

Sheet1:ColumnC is a prefix string and Sheet1:ColumnD is a postfix. I would like to populate Sheet1:ColumnB with the concatenation of Sheet1:ColumnC, the abbreviations from Sheet2:ColumnB and Sheet1:Column D.

e.g.

Sheet1:ColumnA = Gold Silver Bronze

Sheet1:ColumnC = ABC

Sheet1:ColumnD = 123

Sheet2:ColumnA

Row1: Gold

Row2: Silver

Row3: Iron

Sheet2:ColumnB

Row1: Au

Row2: Ag

Row3: Fe

Sheet1:ColumnB = ABCAuAgXX123 (where XX is used for undefined items)

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want the result to look like along with example data from the other sheets? Also, what version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

### A Concat UDF

- In the worksheet `Sheet1` in cell `B1` use the following formula:

  ```
    =ConcElements(C1,A1,D1)
  ```
- Copy the following function into a standard module, e.g. `Module1`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Function ConcElements( _
    ByVal FirstString As String, _
    ByVal ElementsString As String, _
    ByVal ThirdString As String) _
As String
    'Application.Volatile
    
    Dim Elements() As String: Elements = Split(ElementsString)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim eIndex As Variant
    Dim eString As String
    Dim e As Long
    
    For e = 0 To UBound(Elements)
        eIndex = Application.Match(Elements(e), sws.Columns(1), 0)
        If IsError(eIndex) Then
            eString = eString & "Xx"
        Else
            eString = eString & sws.Cells(eIndex, 2).Value
        End If
    Next e
   
    ConcElements = FirstString & eString & ThirdString

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @VBasic2008, this worked exactly as required. I would like to extend this concept further.

Instead of referencing a fixed Sheet2:ColumnB for abbreviations, there are multiple abbreviation columns in a table e.g. Sheet2:ColumnC, D, E. On Sheet1.Cell(B1) there is a string to select the appropriate table column. I've replaced the integer in sws.Cells with a variable (y) and brought in the string from Sheet1:Cell(B1) as a variable (x) but the syntax for the y = Application.Match(x,table[header]) isn't quite right.

Comment: I guess you should ask another question, I consider this one answered.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks.

y = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange.Cells.Find(x).Column

Comment: Rather use `..."Table1").ListColumns(x).Index`.